# Remove A Tab (App) from A Page Using The Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible remove an app from a page using the Open Graph?

From the official documentation they say that is possible: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

But when I use it with the **delete** on the graph explorer:
graph.facebook.com/128003037303086/tabs/app_333139666735547

I am getting this error:

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#210) Subject must be a page.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 210
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/524/

The Graph API Explorer makes it easy to read and update your Page settings interactively. If you get a ‘subject must be a Page’ error, you are likely not using the Page access token for the request.

Comment: So was that what you were doing? not using the page access token?